# How to split string by slash which is not between numbers?

Tags: regex, php-7.2, preg-split

How to split string by slash which is not between numbers?
I am using preg_split function below:

```
$splitted = preg_split('#[/\\\\\_\s]+#u', $string);
```

Input: `"925/123 Black/Jack"`

Splitted result now:

```
[
    0 => '925',
    1 => '123',
    2 => 'Black',
    3 => 'Jack'
]
```

Splitted result I want:

```
[
    0 => '925/123',
    1 => 'Black',
    2 => 'Jack'
]
```

Comment: Would lookarounds be available for you? If so, maybe use lookbehind and lookahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_split('#(?:[\s\\\\_]|(?<!\d)/(?!\d))+#u', '925/123 Black/Jack')
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/hrOpf) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dDVBtL/1) and the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[\s\\_]` - a whitespace, `\` or `_`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<!\d)/(?!\d)` - a `/` not enclosed with digits
- `)+` - end of a non-capturing group, repeat 1 or more times.

Answer (score 1):

One option is match 1 or more digits divided by a forward slash with whitespace boundaries on the left and on the right.

Then use [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex), and match 1 or more times what is listed in the character class. Note that you don't have to escape the underscore.

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?:/\d+)+(?!\S)(*SKIP)(*F)|[/\\_\s]+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)\d+(?:/\d+)+(?!\S)` Match a repeated number of digits between forward slashes
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip
- `|` Or
- `[/\\_\s]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any of the listed

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hSgvkb/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/tdm30)

For example

```
$string = "925/123 Black/Jack";
$pattern = "#(?<!\S)\d+(?:/\d+)+(?!\S)(*SKIP)(*F)|[/\\\\_\s]+#u";
$splitted = preg_split($pattern, $string);
print_r($splitted);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 925/123
    [1] => Black
    [2] => Jack
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is unnecessarily complicated. You need to split your string on:

- either a **space** (maybe more generally - a sequence of white chars),
- or a **slash**

  - not preceded by a digit (negative lookbehind),
  - not followed by a digit (negative lookahead).

So the regex you need (enclosed in *#* chars, with doubled backslashes) is:

```
#(?<!\\d)/(?!\\d)|\\s+#
```

Example of code:

```
$string = "925/123 Black/Jack";
$pattern = "#(?<!\\d)/(?!\\d)|\\s+#";
$splitted = preg_split($pattern, $string);
print_r($splitted);
```

prints just what you want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 925/123
    [1] => Black
    [2] => Jack
)
```